# "Happy to help on this"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

When I normally chat with customers at work, I will say "I am happy to help you with this." Would it also be correct to say "I am happy to help on this." Why?

Comment: Yes; that's short for: I'm happy to help *(you)* on this *(issue)*.

Comment: Grammatically, neither is correct, since the demonstrative pronoun 'this' has no antecedent. In everyday speech, I'd prefer "help you with this" or "help you on this matter", since "help you on this" sounds a bit awkward (maybe just to me).

Comment: @barrycarter The antecedent of *this* can be in another sentence, or understood from the context. When speaking face to face, it can be indicated by a gesture. I don't think antecedents are a grammatical issue.

Answer (score 2):

No-one would ever misunderstand either but strictly, I think *I am happy to help you with this…* would be better as *… with that…* Until we've agreed I'm going to help, that's *your* problem; only afterwards does *this* become *my* or *our* problem.

Similarly *I am happy to help on this* will always be understood, and all kinds of complexities make it strictly wrong.